# Why am I getting a 'transform already exists' error when running this Apache Beam code in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, apache-beam-io

```
import apache_beam as beam

with beam.Pipeline() as p1:
  read_data=(
    p1
    | beam.io.ReadFromText('dept_data.txt')
    | beam.Map(lambda x:x.split(','))
    # | beam.io.WriteToText('data/data1')
  )
  accounts_att=(
      read_data
      | beam.Filter(lambda x:x[3]=='Accounts')
      | beam.Map(lambda x:(x[1],1))
      | beam.CombinePerKey(sum)
      | beam.io.WriteToText('data/Account')
  )
  hr_att=(
      read_data
      | beam.Filter(lambda x:x[3]=='HR')
      | beam.Map(lambda x:(x[1],1))
      | beam.CombinePerKey(sum)
      | beam.io.WriteToText('data/HR')
  )
!{('head -n 20 data/Account-00000-of-00001')}
!{('head -n 20 data/HR-00000-of-00001')}
```

When I run this code, I'm getting this code.

```
RuntimeError: A transform with label "[29]: CombinePerKey(sum)" already exists in the pipeline. To apply a transform with a specified label write pvalue | "label" >> transform.
```

Comment: I've found out what's wrong myself. It has to be labeled distinguishing the beam functions in each branch.  like,  "sumacc" >> and "sumhr" >>